# How to assign value of nested json property to parent object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Say I have json that looks like this:

```
"data": [{
        "name": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
        "TotalCount": 0,
        "UniqueCount": 3,
        "AveragedEntry": {
            "text": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
            "relevance": 0.20341,
        },
        "WeightedEntry": {
            "text": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
            "relevance": "NaN",
        }
}]
```

What I want is an json array of objects that looks like:

```
"data": [{
            "name": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
            "TotalCount": 0,
            "UniqueCount": 3,
            "AveragedEntry": 0.20341,
            "WeightedEntry": "NaN"
    }]
```

Where the parent properties AveragedEntry and WeightedEntry are assigned the value of the relevance property.

There are a A LOT of questions about how to loop through / create / manipulate a json object but I have not come across this particular problem I want to solve.

Is this possible using javascript/jquery?

I have tried making a deep copy of my initial json and looping through the object and pushing the nested object with no luck. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Do you want a different object with that format, or do you want to change your original object to that format?

Comment: @Taplar I would like to return a new object so I can further manipulate it, thanks

Comment: You're going to need to loop by means using the .map function. If you dont want to loop (.map) you're going to have to do it at serialization time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifying `AveragedEntry` and `WeightedEntry`,

You can loop thru the array using `map`. Use `Object.entries` to convert the object into an array and use `reduce` to make a new object.

Check if the value is an object, if it is, use the `relevance` property.

```js
let data = [{"name":"United States Department of Homeland Security","TotalCount":0,"UniqueCount":3,"AveragedEntry":{"text":"United States Department of Homeland Security","relevance":0.20341},"WeightedEntry":{"text":"United States Department of Homeland Security","relevance":"NaN"}}];

//Loop each array element using `.map()`
//variable o holds the array elements.
let result = data.map(o => {
  
  //Use `Object.entries()` to convert each array element (object) into an array
  //This will return a multi dimensional array with element 0 the key and element 1 the value
  //Variable `k` is the key of the object. Like: name, AveragedEntry, WeightedEntry
  //Variable `v` is the corresponding value of the key. Like 0 or  {"text": "United States Department of Homeland Security","relevance": 0.20341,}

  //If the `v` (value) is a type object, use the relevance and assign the value to the accumulator variable `c`
  return Object.entries(o).reduce((c, [k, v]) => {
    if (typeof v === 'object') c[k] = v.relevance;
    else c[k] = v;
    return c;
  }, {});
});

console.log(result);
```

Shorter Version: Use `Object.assign` to add property and value to an object.

```js
let data = [{"name":"United States Department of Homeland Security","TotalCount":0,"UniqueCount":3,"AveragedEntry":{"text":"United States Department of Homeland Security","relevance":0.20341},"WeightedEntry":{"text":"United States Department of Homeland Security","relevance":"NaN"}}]

let result = data.map(o => Object.entries(o).reduce((c, [k, v]) => Object.assign(c, typeof v === 'object' ? {[k]: v.relevance} : {[k]: v}), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it works the best for me and my project. Your way is pretty clean would you mind explaining a bit more about the letter variables/parameters you have used? I think I would like to rename them in my code but want to make sure I know what they are referencing

Comment: @gwar9 I added an explanation. Let me know if you have further clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var test = {
  "data": [{
    "name": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
    "TotalCount": 0,
    "UniqueCount": 3,
    "AveragedEntry": {
      "text": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
      "relevance": 0.20341,
    },
    "WeightedEntry": {
      "text": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
      "relevance": "NaN",
    }
  }]
};

//make a copy of the object
var newThing = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test));

newThing.data.forEach(function(element){
  //unnest the values that you want
  element.AveragedEntry = element.AveragedEntry.relevance;
  element.WeightedEntry = element.WeightedEntry.relevance;
});

//original is not changed
console.log(test);
//new element exists
console.log(newThing);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let data = [{"name": "United States Department of Homeland Security","TotalCount": 0,"UniqueCount": 3,"AveragedEntry": {"text": "United States Department of Homeland Security","relevance": 0.20341,},"WeightedEntry": {"text": "United States Department of Homeland Security","relevance": "NaN",}}];

data = data.map(({AveragedEntry, WeightedEntry, ...rest}) => Object.assign(rest,{AveragedEntry : AveragedEntry.relevance, WeightedEntry : WeightedEntry.relevance}));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.map()` to transform the array to desired structure:

```js
var data = [{
        "name": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
        "TotalCount": 0,
        "UniqueCount": 3,
        "AveragedEntry": {
            "text": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
            "relevance": 0.20341,
        },
        "WeightedEntry": {
            "text": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
            "relevance": "NaN",
        }
}];

var res = data.map((obj)=>{
   obj.AveragedEntry = obj.AveragedEntry.relevance;
   obj.WeightedEntry = obj.WeightedEntry.relevance;
   return obj;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Since the `obj` is a nested element, changing its contents is also going to affect the original, which the OP did not want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create a pipeline for data transforms like this.

```js
let data = [{
        "name": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
        "TotalCount": 0,
        "UniqueCount": 3,
        "AveragedEntry": {
            "text": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
            "relevance": 0.20341,
        },
        "WeightedEntry": {
            "text": "United States Department of Homeland Security",
            "relevance": "NaN",
        }
}];

// Map the data into the new data structure.
var mapped = data.map(e => ({ 
    name: e.name, 
    totalCount: e.TotalCount, 
    uniqueCount: e.UniqueCount,
    averagedEntry: e.AveragedEntry.relevance,
    weightedEntry: e.WeightedEntry.relevance
}));

console.log(mapped)
```

This might be a bit more wordy that some of the answers that use the JavaScript meta-programming api, but I think simplicity is best for readability.